# Should I distribute the Dataset XSD files when I deploy as website?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

VS 2003 .NET 1.1

I know when I build a website into a DLL I do not have to distribute the cs files.

When my project includes strongly typed datasets built off an XSD file, should I also distribute the XSD file, or does the generated cs file (and thus the DLL) contain all the required information to use the Dataset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated cs file (and thus the DLL) contain all the required information to create instances of your strongly typed DataSet classes.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I just wanted a 2nd opinion. :)